# Error thrown after installing structr snapshot 3.5 on debian buster

Tags: structr

I installed the 3.5 snapshot over version 3.4.3. the later was running fine. 3.5 threw an error on startup:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Ausnahmebedingung in Thread "main"# START NON-TRANSLATABLEjava.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
JVMCFRE003 Ungültige übergeordnete Version; Klasse=org/structr/Server, Offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:682)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:89)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1086)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:770)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:953)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:898)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:881)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

I'm on debian buster with openjdk-8-jdk installed.
Do I need to upgrade java to 11 for 3.5 or is there something else I'm missing?

**Update**: installed jdk-11. change Neo4j version from 4.0.3 to 3.5.17 (thanks goes to Kai Schwaiger for trouble shooting), everything works as expected after setting the right memory config for neo4j and structr. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.5 will be the first version that needs JDK 11, we just haven't documented the fact. Sorry :(

So yes, you need JDK 11. :)

Comment: Thanks and good to know ;) 
I guess a need to install a seperate neo4j db or will structr solve this?
also this comes up in the strctr.log:
`020-04-22 14:25:49.792 [main] WARN  o.s.s.export.StructrTypeDefinition - Unable to resolve built-in type https://structr.org/v1.1/definitions/ConceptGroup against Structr schema`

and this in the backend upper right corner:

`Currently running on an in-memory database implementation. Data is no persisted and will be lost after restarting the instance! You can use the configuration servlet to configure a database connection.`

Comment: 3.5 is also the first version to come without embedded Neo4j, so yes, you need to install Neo4j and copy or link the db directory into Neo4j (data/databases/graph.db).

Comment: Ok, I tried, but maybe missed something:  
I installed neoj4 CE. 
erased the default database created by neo4j (data/databases/neo4j),  
created a Sym Link from structr/db to data/database/neo4j  
but it's still not working  
beforehand I tried to connect "remotely" via /structr/conf that failed as well
neo4j log says bolt is runnin' for localhost on default port and I confirmed with ss.  
what do I miss? :/

Comment: You need to go to the Neo4j browser at http://localhost:7474 and log in to change the default password, otherwise Neo4j doesn't allow remote connections. Can you share the structr log file / output?

Comment: I changed neo4j's password trough cypher-shell.  I can log into the db via cypher shell.   so the credentials work. lsof -i | grep 7687 gives me: `java    52463    neo4j   TCP localhost:7687 (LISTEN)`  
[structr.log](https://pastebin.com/SytbQFE5)

Comment: now neo4j went nuts: I created a sym link from data/database to structr/db. neo4j throw an error regarding as storeid mismatch, so it failed starting. I removed all databases. started neo4j again. database files are created but start up fails again. .

Comment: With the help of Kai Schwaiger I solved the issue:
Had neo4j 4.0.3 installed, what obviously didn't work.
Installed neo4j 3.5.17, configured neo4j and structr (memory size) and it's runnung. thanks for your help! :)